# java script Regular Expressions patterns problem

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

My problem start with like-

```
var str='0|31|2|03|.....|4|2007'
str=str.replace(/[^|]\d*[^|]/,'5');
```

so the output becomes like:"0|**5**|2|03|....|4|2007" so it replaces 31->5

But this doesn't work for replacing other segments when i change code like this:

```
str=str.replace(/[^|]{2}\d*[^|]/,'6');
```

doesn't change 2->6.
What actually i am missing here.Any help?

Comment: I accidently clicked the DOWNVOTE button. I can't undo it until the post is edited. Please edit it and I will remove the DOWNVOTE. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a specific regex solution which replaces the number following the first `|` pipe symbol with the number `5`:

```js
var re = /^((?:\d+\|){1})\d+/;
return text.replace(re, '$15');
```

If you want to replace the digits following the third `|`, simply change the `{1}` portion of the regex to `{3}`

Here is a generalized function that will replace any given number slot (zero-based index), with a specified new number:

```js
function replaceNthNumber(text, n, newnum) {
    var re = new RegExp("^((?:\\d+\\|){"+ n +'})\\d+');
    return text.replace(re, '$1'+ newnum);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think a regular expression is a bad solution for that problem. I'd rather do something like this:

```
var str = '0|31|2|03|4|2007';
var segments = str.split("|");
segments[1] = "35";
segments[2] = "123";
```

Can't think of a good way to solve this with a regexp.

Comment: str = str.replace(/(^|[|])\d+(?=[|]|$)/g, '$1' + 5)

Comment: thanks katspaugh but ur solution makes all segment to 5.What i actually want is to change each segment to individual input.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you don't have to escape `|` in the character set, because it doesn't have any special meaning in character sets.

Secondly, you don't put quantifiers in character sets.

And finally, to create a global matching expression, you have to use the `g` flag.

Comment: well i know about \g but what i want is to change specific index/segment to each individual input.Do you have any solution then?

Comment: You can use `replace` with a function-replacer. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Example.3a_Using_an_inline_function_that_modifies_the_matched_characters

Answer (score 2):

[^\|] means anything but a '|', so in your case it only matches a digit. So it will only match anything with 2 or more digits.

Second you should put the {2} outside of the []-brackets

I'm not sure what you want to achieve here.